# Php get specific word of string

Tags: php, string, function, text

What is the php function to extract only the word `Duitsland` from the following string `/Duitsland|/groepsreizen fietsen|Stars/1`.

I tried everything but dit not find the right method.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/de/function.str-replace.php

```
$result= str_replace("Duitsland", "", "/Duitsland|/groepsreizen fietsen|Stars/1");
```

Result: `"/|/groepsreizen fietsen|Stars/1"`

Comment: Thx my question was wrong I want to use only the first word from the string. 'Duitsland'. I don't need the rest '/groepsreizen fietsen|Stars/1

Comment: @FrankvanLeeuwen please see my answer if I understood you properly.

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple way to do this work. One way is using regex. Use regex in [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to finding specific word of string.

```
$str = "/Duitsland|/groepsreizen fietsen|Stars/1";
preg_match("/[^|\/]+/", $str, $match);
echo $match[0];
```

You can test it in [demo](https://ideone.com/4T9JZ6)

Answer (score 0):

```
with strpos function find require o/p
$haystack = '/Duitsland|/groepsreizen fietsen|Stars/1';
$needle = 'Duitsland';

if (strpos($haystack,$needle) !== false) {
    echo $needle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:
(this code does not need to know what is the word before, it just seeks the first (as long as possible) word in the string)

```
<?php

$str = "/Duitsland|/groepsreizen fietsen|Stars/1";

preg_match("/\w+/i", $str, $matches);

$first_word = array_shift($matches);

echo $first_word;
```

It will work no matter how many non-letter symbols there are before that word, i.e. it's not dependent on any fixed-count other characters.

Demo: http://ideone.com/GX8IT6